# React hooks not being set properly with JSON API response

Tags: reactjs

I have tried setting my hooks to useState(null) useState([]) and useState() for initial page load, all with no success.

result.data and result.labels inside the fetch method all log to console with the appropriate data, but everytime I call setGraphData or setGraphLabels it just refuses to transfer the data to the hook variables

JSON Response:

Success true

labels  [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", … ]

data    [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]

0   Object { label: "", data: null, borderColor: "", … }

1   Object { label: "Kyle", borderColor: "#f6ff00", backgroundColor: "#f6ff00", … }

label   "Kyle"

data    [ "1517", "1689", "1719", "1591", "1490", "1310", "1533", "1500", "1400", "1300", … ]

borderColor "#f6ff00"

backgroundColor "#f6ff00"

2   Object { label: "Biprodeep", borderColor: "#ff0000", backgroundColor: "#ff0000", … }

3   Object { label: "Archisman", borderColor: "#001eff", backgroundColor: "#001eff", … }

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js'
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
)

function UploadFile() {

  const [graphData, setGraphData] = React.useState(null);
  const [graphDataFinal, setGraphDataFinal] = React.useState(null);
  const [graphLabels, setGraphLabels] = React.useState(null);
  const [isUploaded, setIsUploaded] = React.useState(false);
  var graphDataSets = [];

  function dropHandler(ev) {
    console.log('File(s) dropped');
  
    // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
    if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
        // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[0].kind === 'file') {
          var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFile();
          var data = new FormData()
          data.append('file', file)

          fetch('http://192.168.1.94:8081/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: data,
            headers: {
              'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('session-id')
            },
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            DrawGraph(result.data, result.labels);
            setIsUploaded(true);
          },
          // Note: it's important to handle errors here
          // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
          // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
        }
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

  function dragOverHandler(ev) {
    console.log('File(s) in drop zone');
  
    // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function DrawGraph(data, labels) {
    console.log("Draw Graph Executed")
    setGraphData(data);
    setGraphLabels(labels);
    for (var x in graphData) {
      if (x === 0) {
        
      } else {
        graphDataSets.push({ id: x, label: graphData[x].label, data: graphData[x].data, borderColor: graphData[x].borderColor, backgroundColor: graphData[x].backgroundColor })
      }
    }
    setGraphDataFinal(graphDataSets);
    console.log(graphDataFinal);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="drop_zone" onDrop={dropHandler} onDragOver={dragOverHandler}>
        <p className="drop_zone">Drag one or more files to upload and generate a graph</p>
      </div>
      <br></br>
        {isUploaded ? <div className="graph-area"><Line
          datasetIdKey='myLine'
          data={{
            labels: graphLabels,
            datasets: graphDataFinal,
          }}
        /></div> : null}
    </div>
    )
}

export default UploadFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React does not immediately updates state so in function draw graph use data variable in for loop instead of graphData and update code as well which you want immediate effect/change in state.

```
function DrawGraph(data, labels) {
console.log("Draw Graph Executed")
setGraphData(data);
setGraphLabels(labels);
for (var x in data) {
  if (x === 0) {
    
  } else {
    graphDataSets.push({ id: x, label: graphData[x].label, data: graphData[x].data, borderColor: graphData[x].borderColor, backgroundColor: graphData[x].backgroundColor })
  }
}
setGraphDataFinal(graphDataSets);
console.log(graphDataSets);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Not sure why the hooks weren't working right though

Comment: Please read this article for more details:
https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately